# Entity framework 5 database first - hide properties

Tags: c#, odata, entity-framework-5

I have an entity framework model developed from an existing database. I have separated the models into a separate class so they can only be updated manually hoping this would give the capacity to add the [IgnoreDataMember] attribute to certain properties. I am trying to prevent some properties of my objects being serialized in the odata response.

For example http://localhost:11776/dataservice.svc/Users(53) will return all of the properties for user ID 53 - including the hashed passwords, salts etc - I want to limit the odata response to just the vanilla info.

I am aware that I can use a service when I want a specific record, but I need to solve the general case - for example when users are returned as a property of another class.

Anyway - the [IgnoreDataMember] seems to have no effect. I do not specify [Datacontract] - so I thought that this should be the business.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT:
Entity Framework V5.0

```
Microsoft.Data.OData.dll 

EntityFramework.dll

Microsoft.Data.Edm 

All v4.0.3019
```

Comment: Can you tell us what's library you are using to build odata service? And which version?